# Which is the correct GaAs{001}(2×4) structure?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, nanoscience

When trying to understand the [GaAs 2x4 surface reconstruction](http://newton.ex.ac.uk/research/qsystems/people/jenkins/smg/gaas/gaas_001_beta2_2x4.html), I came across the following statement:

*"Because the periodicity of the surface has doubled (compared to the bulk periodicity) in the direction parallel to the trenches, and quadrupled in the direction perpendicular to the trenches, this is known as a $(2 \times 4)$ reconstruction."*

[image: Figure 1]

**I don't think I understand what the bulk periodicity is in this case. How has it doubled, and what caused it to do so?**

My understanding is that the bulk periodicity is the simplest form of the structure (inside the white box in the first image), the smallest one, which has then been doubled in one direction and quadrupled in the other direction (sort of like a matrix). **But I don't see quadrupling, it seems to me that the structure is merely doubling in both directions.**

Another image (moved around slightly differently) is this one:

[image: Figure 2]

But to me this still seems to be a $(2 \times 2)$ which is lacking the second trench.

Another image I have found can be shown below, but this to me seems to be even more incomplete than the others, as with my thinking (which I know to be wrong) it would be a $(1 \times 1)$ .

[image: Figure 3]

This question comes as a consequence of trying to answer a question that I have previously posted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605577/how-do-i-sketch-a-2x1-dimer-structures-on-the-001-surfaces-of-a-zinc-blende) and I am hoping it will help me solve the previous question.

**How is my point of view wrong? How do these images (specially the first two) represent a GaAs{001}(2×4) structure**

Comment: It is quite clear that the white box in the top illustration is of size 2x4 times that of an ideally terminated surface.

Comment: It might be clear for you but not for me, as this is completely new and I have no sort of background in the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk periodicity doesn't refer to the simplest structure on the surface, it refers to the lattice vectors within the bulk of the crystal where the effects of surface reconstruction are negligible (or alternatively, an ideally terminated surface before it relaxes into a reconstructed configuration).  Consider this diagram from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_reconstruction):

[image]

In this instance, bulk periodicity refers to the spacing of the dark blue circles in the lower two rows.  The light blue circles in the *top* row are forming a surface reconstruction.

If we call the spacing between dark blue circles $d$, you can see that the surface pattern repeats with spacing $2d$.  One would say that the bulk periodicity has doubled in this reconstruction.
[image]

If the spacing in the perpendicular direction is left unchanged, so the surface reconstruction forms nice dimer rows, then we would call this a 2x1 reconstruction.  [This paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-7682-2_11) has a diagram of the 2x1 reconstruction of Si(100):

[image]

The left image shows a (100) lattice plane deep within the crystal, so it has no surface reconstruction; the right image shows the same lattice plane relaxed into a lower-energy surface configuration.

---

Here's a more explicit drawing for your example:

[image]

Comment: I still don't 100% understand it even though the x-axis makes perfect sense now, because to me the distance between the elements in the y-axis is the same as the distance between the elements in the x-axis (I am looking at the second image),it looks to me that is a $(2 \times 2)$ instead of a$(2 \times 4)$. My apologies for bothering you with this.

Comment: @user7077252 Does the updated picture help?

Comment: Oh of course, sorry for that. That makes perfect sense. This is all super new to me. Thank you once more.

Comment: @user7077252 No problem.  Surface reconstructions are one of those things that are entirely obvious once you see the pattern, but remarkably opaque when you don't.

Comment: This means that to replicate this but as a $(2 \times 1)$ structure, vertically the distance would be doubled as above, but horizontally there would be no difference, so it would just like that last structure for Si, right?

Comment: @user7077252 If the atoms had no horizontal deviation but they grouped together vertically as above, then yes that would be 2x1 reconstruction, which manifests as dimer rows.