# How is ECR (Electron Counting Rule) done in a structure?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, nanoscience

I've been told how to apply the ECR to GaAs{001}(2×4) in my lectures but it makes no sense to me and I don't seem to be able to find any other sources that explain this. (This is a further question on another one posted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605758/which-is-the-correct-gaas0012%c3%974-structure/605763?noredirect=1#comment1363719_605763) .)

**Could anyone please tell me how this is done? Or give me some sources on how to apply the ECR?**

---

This is the explanation I have been given for the following structure:

[image]

Count the number of electrons, going down to two of As atoms level with the bottom of the trench and count per unit mesh. There are 8+4 As atoms = 60 valence electrons. There are 6 Ga atoms = 18 electrons. Hence a total of 78 electrons.

*Count the bonds that need to be filled :*

*1. 3 As dimer bonds = 6 e*

*2. 6 As dangling bonds (2 per dimer) = 12 e*

*3. Ga dangling bonds (sideways into trench) are empty = 0 e*

*4. 8 backbonds from top As dimers = 16 e*

*5. 12 backbonds from Ga to 3rd row As = 24 e*

*6. 16 backbonds (bulk-like) from 3rd row As to underlying Ga: each takes 5/4 e from As giving 5×16/4 = 20 e*

*78 electrons for both totals so structure is neutral and should be stable.*

I am trying to learn how to do this as I am trying to prove that this is not applicable to the GaAS{001}(2x1) structure, which I believe to be represented like the image below from the help I was given at a previous related question, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605758/which-is-the-correct-gaas0012%c3%974-structure).

Why does the last point mention that each bond counts for 5/4 of an electron?
[image]

Comment: You can also try chemistry.stackexchange.